# WebApi returng wrong value DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi, webapi

Im trying to get a specific value from a query, but its always returning the same wrong result:

Response body
Download
{
"periodo": "2021-06-21T00:00:00",
"valor": 0
}

But when I try the same query in Sql it return the right value, and not 0 as it shows on Swagger

```
  public  async Task<Test> GetTestValue(string initialDate, string endDate, string id)
        {

            //DateTime dti = new DateTime(2000, 01, 01, 00, 00, 00);
            //DateTime dtf = new DateTime(2022, 01, 01, 00, 00, 00);
            //DateTime dti = new DateTime(2000, 01, 01);
            //DateTime dtf = new DateTime(2022, 01, 01);
            string dti = "2001-01-20";
            string dtf = "2022-01-10";
            DateTime inicio = Convert.ToDateTime(dti);
            DateTime fim = Convert.ToDateTime(dtf);

            var query = @"Select SUM(VlBruto) as 'Monthly Value'
            from tb.testValue ttv
            where idTest = @id and DtReference >= CAST(@i AS DATETIME) and DtReference <= CAST( @e AS DATETIME)";

            var res =  _wizDBDapperContext.DapperConnection.QuerySingleOrDefault<PeriodoComissao>(query, new { doc = cnpj, i = inicio, e = fim});
            return res;
        }
```

What can I change i  the code to return the right value?

If someone has any doubt about the code, I can clarify in the answers. Thanks for helping!

Comment: So you know about Dapper and you even know about parameters (although `= '@id2'` should be `= @id2`, no quotes), so how do you still manage to slip in string concatenation for queries? Parse `initialDate` and `endDate` into `DateTime`s on the client side end and pass them as (properly typed) parameters, don't go injecting strings into your queries.

Comment: I know some stuff in that code are not on the proper way, I tried a lot of stuff and some trash stayed in that code, Im going to edit the post to put it in a proper way and with more stuff that I tried and still returned 0 on swagger.